# Literallycanvas buttons are not clickable. Able to load the UI but only pencil by default is working & no other icon in existing angular 9 application

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, canvas, html5-canvas

[only pencil enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtBbu.png)

basic app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zmtbjy?

Below is my app config and the above basic app of literallycanvas is not working with this configuration. with new project created, literallycanvas is working fine.

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "assessment-player-app",
  "version": "3.0.7",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:player": "ng build --configuration=production --output-hashing=none --single-bundle && node build-elements.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0",
    "literallycanvas": "^0.5.2",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-create-class": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom-factories": "^1.0.2",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.6.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "tippy.js": "^4.3.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.3.2",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.4.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^9.0.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.1"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "assessment-player-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:build",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/assessment-player-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.png"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/literallycanvas/lib/css/literallycanvas.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "assessment-player-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "assessment-player-app:build:prod"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "assessment-player-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.png"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "assessment-player-app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "assessment-player-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "assessment-player-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "assessment-player-app"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "name": "assessment-player-app",
  "version": "3.0.7",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:player": "ng build --configuration=production --output-hashing=none --single-bundle && node build-elements.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0",
    "literallycanvas": "^0.5.2",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-create-class": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom-factories": "^1.0.2",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.6.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "tippy.js": "^4.3.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.3.2",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.4.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^9.0.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.1"
  }
}
```

I have been trying to use literallyCanvas in my existing angular project but the icons are not clickable. Only pencil is active by default.
I tried creating new project from scratch and there it is working as expected. [literallycanvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/literallycanvas)

Comment: Please share sample code.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zmtbjy?file=package.json

Comment: This is the sample code, which is working fine but in my existing application none of the tools are clickable

Comment: I am wondering why you are using a package `literallycanvas` in an ng project which has React as dependency.